# Change return key (returnKeyType) on a contenteditable div in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard, contenteditable

I would like to have a different returnKeyType on my keyboard when editing a contenteditable div in a UIWebView on iOS.

I tried putting the contenteditable div inside a form and assigning it a title/type "search", but this doesn't work. The return key on the keyboard still says "return".

Here is the current code:

```
<form>
<div type="search" id="query" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" title="search">
</form>
```

Is it possible to change the return key for a contenteditable div?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the only way to do this is overlaying the return key on the keyboard with an image.